# Anyone can see what's wrong with this simple Oracle function?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

The function is suppose to return the date in a different format, that's all. Can't see what's wrong with it!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION get_cpd(a_date in varchar2)return varchar2
IS
cpd varchar2(4);
BEGIN
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a_date,'YY/MM/DD'),'YDDD') INTO cpd FROM DUAL;
RETURN cpd;
END get_CPD;
```

Comment: First of all you should tell us why you think it's wrong.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with it - it compiles and runs. The `YDDD` looks odd though, as it gives a single digit for the year; `get_cpd('13/04/11')` gives `3101`... so what do you think is wrong, and why? Might the problem be with how you're calling it (e.g. passing a `DATE` rather than a `VARCHAR2` as the argument)? Using `YY` is a bit dangerous, and you don't need the `cpd` variable, but those aren't necessarily errors.

Comment: Hi Tanks for replying, i get an error when I call it stating that the select statement is incomplete.

This is how I'm calling it:

select * from get_CPD('13/04/10');

Actually the exact error is:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you you call a function. In Oracle you have to select from something, always. If you don't have an actual table to select data from then use the built-in single-row table `DUAL`:

```
select get_cpd('13/04/10') from dual;
```

If it's part of a larger query then you can pass in a column value:

```
select get_cpd(some_column) from some_table;
```

If you're calling it from another PL/SQL block or from some other client then you don't have to have a `select`, e.g.

```
declare
    cpd varchar2(4);
begin
    cpd := get_cpd('13/04/10');
end;
/
```

... but that assumes you'll be doing something with the value rather than just displaying it.

Incidentally, you can simplify your function to take advantage of that way of calling `to_char`:

```
create or replace function get_cpd(a_date in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
begin
    return to_char(to_date(a_date,'YY/MM/DD'),'YDDD');
end get_cpd;
/

select get_cpd('13/04/11') from dual;

GET_CPD('13/04/11')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3101
```

You should probably also use `RR` rather than `YY` for two-digit years, but check the docs.